# arduino executes serial commands only sometimes

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have been trying to make an arduino project which changes the motor directions based on serial input.
I have tried everything on google search. the arduino only responds sometimes. I know my board is not fried because the same happens on other boards.

code:

```
 const int motorApinA = 6;
  const int motorApinB = 7;
  const int motorBpinA = 8;
  const int motorBpinB = 9;
  const int LED_Strip_pos_pin = 2;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(motorApinA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorApinB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorBpinA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorBpinB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_Strip_pos_pin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.write("yay, your code is working");


}

void loop() 
  {
     if (Serial.read() == 'F')
     {
       digitalWrite(motorApinA, HIGH);
       digitalWrite(motorApinB, LOW);
       digitalWrite(motorBpinB, HIGH);
       digitalWrite(motorBpinA, LOW);
       Serial.println("Done!");
     }
     if (Serial.read() == 'B')
     {
       digitalWrite(motorApinB, HIGH);
       digitalWrite(motorApinA, LOW);
       digitalWrite(motorBpinA, HIGH);
       digitalWrite(motorBpinB, LOW);
       Serial.println("Done!");

     }
     if (Serial.read() == 'L')
     {
       digitalWrite(motorApinA, HIGH);
       digitalWrite(motorApinB, LOW);
       digitalWrite(motorBpinA, HIGH);
       digitalWrite(motorBpinB, LOW);
       Serial.println("Done!");

     }
     if (Serial.read() == 'R')
     {
       digitalWrite(motorApinB, HIGH);
       digitalWrite(motorApinA, LOW);
       digitalWrite(motorBpinB, HIGH);
       digitalWrite(motorBpinA, LOW);
       Serial.println("Done!");

     }
     if (Serial.read() == 'S')
     {
       digitalWrite(motorApinA, LOW);
       digitalWrite(motorApinB, LOW);
       digitalWrite(motorBpinB, LOW);
       digitalWrite(motorBpinA, LOW);
       Serial.println("Done!");
     }

     }
```

sorry if I asked this on the wrong site :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call `Serial.read()`, it reads the first char in the buffer. Let's say you have a `'B'` in your buffer. Unless your program happens to be at `if (Serial.read() == 'B')`, it doesn't trigger the action you want. You should store a returned value from `Serial.read()` and evaluate it.

```cpp
void loop()  {

  char c = Serial.read();

  if (c == 'F') {
    Serial.println("F!");
  }

  if (c == 'B') {
    Serial.println("B!");
  }

  if (c == 'L') {
    Serial.println("L!");
  }

  if (c == 'R') {
    Serial.println("R!");
  }

  if (c == 'S') {
    Serial.println("S!");
  }
}
```